# Can't connect to local joomla database

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

I m trying to diplay `introtext` from mysql into a module, and I can't connect with the local db...  Any advice?

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
mysql_query($query);
```

Output:

> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server

Any help? The more basic is the subject the less we can find information about it!

Comment: I m veey good to make special error. Thanks a lot! Well I m a very little baby php, I fund that piece of code in different forum and tut. No idea what's the `$db` could you please write the code I should use, I didnt understand. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use joomla methods instead of `mysql_query()`

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE Id=127";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult();
```

In general the [Joomla documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase#loadResult.28.29) is your friend

Comment: Thank you Renick! I tried that '<?php
 JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult(); 
?>  ` but it display a white page with `Notice: Undefined variable: db in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function setQuery() on a non-object in /homez.420/kmxsiksf/rscmovement.org/modules/mod_jumi/tmpl/default.php(12) : eval()'d code on line 4`

Comment: Sorry i did forgot a line the whole code is half working : the code is written into a module that is load in the home page content : the template is cut and there is an empy line where the introtext is suppose to appear  (no text appear) whole code `<?php
$db =&  JFactory::getDBO();
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM jmo_content WHERE Id=127";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult(); 
?>  `

Comment: You need to `echo $text;` for any output to appear

Comment: It is working!!! 2 days I m on it! Thank you so much! Ah I understand it a bit better! Thanks for your patience !

Comment: Dont worry it gets easier with time. Just needs some reading to nail the basics. And dont forget to mark correct answers otherwise stackers will tend not to answer.

Comment: I m connecting with a phone I do not see any "mark correct answer option". (i did spend 2 days to find out about mysql, and this last non working code piece)

Comment: Got it from the desktop, have a beautiful day!

Comment: The graal: a code to display any content from joomla database into php module jumi 


`<?php $db =& JFactory::getDBO(); 
$query = "SELECT introtext FROM #__content WHERE Id=127";
$db->setQuery($query);
$text= $db->loadResult(); ?>`

`<?php echo $text; ?>`